# Estoy haciendo un Select a parir de otro Estado, municipio, parroquia, comunidad

Tags: javascript, postgresql, mvc, select

En el Js

```
/*cargar_parroquia_por_municipio*/
$("#id_parroquia").change(function () {

    $("#id_parroquia option:selected").each(function () {

        var id_parroquia = $(this).val();
        //alert(id_municipio);
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../Controlador/CtrlComunidad.php",
            data: {
                id_parroquia: id_parroquia,
                cargar_comunidad_por_parroquia: "cargar_comunidad_por_parroquia"
            },
            success: function (respuesta) {
                $("#id_comunidad").html("<option value=''>SELECCIONE UN MUNICIPIO</option>" + respuesta);
            },
            beforeSend: function () { },
            error: function (objXMLHttpRequest) { }
        });
    });
});
```

En el controlador

```
if (isset($_POST['cargar_comunidad_por_parroquia'])) {

   include_once '../Modelo/Comunidad.php';

   $Comunidad = new Comunidad();

   $id_parroquia = $_POST['id_parroquia'];

   $Comunidad = $Comunidad->cargarComunidad($id_parroquia);

   foreach ($comunidad as $row) {

      echo '<option value="' . $row['id_comunidad'] . '">' . $row['nombre_comunidad'] . '</option>';
   }
}
```

En el Modelo

```
public function cargarComunidad( $id_parroquia){
    
    $tiraSQL = "SELECT comunidad.* FROM public.comunidad,public.parroquia WHERE comunidad.status ='true' AND parroquia.id_parroquia = comunidad.id_parroquia AND comunidad.id_parroquia = '".$id_parroquia."';";
    
    $resul= pg_query($tiraSQL);
    
    $i = 0;
    
    $filas = array();
    while($datos = pg_fetch_array($resul)){

        $filas[$i]['id_comunidad'] = $datos['id_comunidad'];
        $filas[$i]['nombre_comunidad'] = $datos['nombre_comunidad'];
        $filas[$i]['id_parroquia'] = $datos['id_parroquia'];

        $i++;
    }
    return $filas;
    
}
```

Funciona bien hasta parroquia pero no logro traer la comunidad a un Select. debería ser el mismo principio pero no se por que no se trae los datos de la tabla Comunidad,

Así tengo creado mis tablas en PostgreSQL.

```
create table estado
(
    id_estado serial primary key,
    nombre_estado varchar(50) not null unique,
    status boolean not null default true
);

create table municipio
(
    id_municipio serial primary key,
    nombre_municipio varchar(50) not null unique,
    id_estado integer not null,
    status boolean not null default true,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_estado) REFERENCES estado(id_estado)
);

create table parroquia
(
    id_parroquia serial primary key,
    nombre_parroquia varchar(50) not null unique,
    id_municipio integer not null,
    status boolean not null default true,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_municipio) REFERENCES municipio(id_municipio)
);

create table comunidad
(
    id_comunidad serial primary key,
    nombre_comunidad varchar(50) not null unique,
    id_parroquia integer not null,
    status boolean not null default true,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_parroquia) REFERENCES parroquia(id_parroquia)
);
```

Comment: Posiblemente sea que en tu controlador estás sobrescribiendo la variable `$Comunidad`... ya que primero instancias la clase `Comunidad` y luego lo sobrescribes al acceder a uno de sus métodos... procura usar distintas variables, por ejemplo: `$comunidadModel = new Comunidad();` y `$comunidad = $comunidadModel->cargarComunidad($id_parroquia);`

Comment: tambien pense eso, y cambie el nombre de la clase del Modelo y nombre de la variable. pero aun nada y no entiendo porque no me trae los datos al Select